# LINQ statements to do a nested list of DynamicTableEntities in chunks of 100

Tags: c#, .net, linq, azure-table-storage

I am attempting to create batches of 100 records i can delete from Azure Table Storage.  I found a great article on efficiently creating batches to delete table records here: https://blog.bitscry.com/2019/03/25/efficiently-deleting-rows-from-azure-table-storage/

and have followed this along.  the issue i am facing that is different from the example in this blog post is that my deletes will have different partition keys.  so rather than simply splitting my results into batches of 100 (as it does in the example) i first need to split them into groups of like partition keys, and THEN examine those lists, and further sub-divide them if the count is greater than 100 (as Azure recommends only batches of 100 records at a time, and they all require the same partition key)

Let me say i am TERRIBLE with enumerable LINQ and the non-query style that is described in this blog post so i'm a bit lost.  i have written a small work around that does create these batches by the partition ID, and the code works to delete them, i just am not handling the possibility that there may be more than 100 rows to delete based on the partition key.  So the code below is just used as an example to show you how i approached splitting the updates by partition key.

```
List<string> partitionKeys = toDeleteEntities.Select(x => x.PartitionKey).Distinct().ToList();

List<List<DynamicTableEntity>> chunks = new List<List<DynamicTableEntity>>();

for (int i = 0; i < partitionKeys.Count; ++i)
 {
  var count = toDeleteEntities.Where(x => x.PartitionKey == partitionKeys[i]).Count();
          //still need to figure how to split by groups of 100.
         chunks.Add(toDeleteEntities.Distinct().Where(x=>x.PartitionKey == partitionKeys[i]).ToList());
 }
```

i have tried to do multiple groupby statements in a linq function similar to this

```
// Split into chunks of 100 for batching
        List<List<TableEntity>> rowsChunked = tableQueryResult.Result.Select((x, index) => new { Index = index, Value = x })
            .Where(x => x.Value != null)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 100)
            .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();
```

but once i add a second set parameters to group by (eg: x=>x.PartitionKey) then my select below starts to go pear shaped.  The end result object is a LIST of LISTS that contain DyanmicTableEntities and an index

```
[0]
  [0][Entity]
  [1][Entity]
   ...
  [99][Entity]
[1]
  [0][Entity]
  [1][Entity]
   ...
```

i hope this makes sense, if not please feel free to ask for clarification.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:

The idea is simply that i want to group by PARTITION Key AND only take 100 rows before creating another row of the SAME partition key and adding the rest of the rows

thanks,

Comment: What do you expect to get, can you provide an example of it. What exactly are you trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One useful LINQ method you can use is [GroupBy(keySelector)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1). It basically divides your collection into groups based on a selector. So in your case, you'd probably want to group by PartitionKey:

```cs
var partitionGroups = toDeleteEntities.GroupBy(d => d.PartitionKey);
```

When you iterate through this collection, you'll get an [IGrouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=netcore-3.1). Finally, to get the correct batch, you can use [Skip(int count)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netcore-3.1) and [Take(int count)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netcore-3.1)

```cs
    foreach (var  partitionGroup  in  partitionGroups)
    {
        var  partitionKey = partitionGroup.Key;
        int  startPosition = 0;
        int  count = partitionGroup.Count();

        while(count > 0)
        {
            int  batchSize = count % maxBatchSize > 0 ? count % maxBatchSize : maxBatchSize;

            var  partitionBatch = partitionGroup.Skip(startPosition).Take(batchSize);
            // process your batches here
            chunks.Add(new  List<DynamicTableEntry>(partitionBatch));

            startPosition += batchSize;
            count = count - batchSize;
        }
    }
```